# Изменить цвет текста в другом div при нажатии в предыдущем div input type="checkbox"

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox, label

Необходимо изменить цвет текста в другом div (control-label) при нажатии в предыдущем div (controls) на input type="checkbox".

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
<input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" id="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" value="1" aria-required="true" class="required"></div>
<div class="control-label">
<a data-role="gdpr_privacy_policy" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
<label title="Вот">Вот для этого текста нужно поменять цвет при нажатии на input checkbox</label>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Или JS или изменять разметку. В том виде, как сейчас, только через CSS это сделать не получится.

Comment: Изменять разметку слишком муторно. Посторонний компонент. А если через js?

Comment: Получите label, получите checkbox.   el.слушатель(событие, функция)   выполните событие клика,  когда  елемент input.   input.classList.toggle('класс для label')  Тут стоит понимать как еще событие погружается и что происходит при всплытии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" id="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" value="1" aria-required="true" class="required" onclick="document.querySelector('div.control-label label').style.color = (this.checked) ? 'red' : '';">
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <a data-role="gdpr_privacy_policy" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
      <label title="Вот">Вот для этого текста нужно поменять цвет при нажатии на input checkbox</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или так:

```js
document.getElementById('gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  document.querySelector('div.control-label label').style.color = (this.checked) ? 'red' : ''
});
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" id="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" value="1" aria-required="true" class="required">
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <a data-role="gdpr_privacy_policy" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
      <label title="Вот">Вот для этого текста нужно поменять цвет при нажатии на input checkbox</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для динамически добавляемых блоков:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName != 'INPUT') { return false; }
  ev.target.closest('.control-group').querySelector('div.control-label label').style.color = (ev.target.checked) ? 'red' : '';
});
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" id="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" value="1" aria-required="true" class="required">
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <a data-role="gdpr_privacy_policy" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
      <label title="Вот">Вот для этого текста нужно поменять цвет при нажатии на input checkbox</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" id="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" value="1" aria-required="true" class="required">
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <a data-role="gdpr_privacy_policy" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
      <label title="Вот">Вот для этого текста нужно поменять цвет при нажатии на input checkbox</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если стилизация не ограничивается одним свойством, то добавляем/удаляем CSS-класс:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.name == 'gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox') {
  ev.target.closest('.control-group').querySelector('div.control-label label').classList.toggle('check', ev.target.checked); }
});
```

```css
.check {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" id="gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox" value="1" aria-required="true" class="required">
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <a data-role="gdpr_privacy_policy" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">
      <label title="Вот">Вот для этого текста нужно поменять цвет при нажатии на input checkbox</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! а можно событие onclick вытащить отдельно в код js?

Comment: Вот! Спасибо Большое)

Comment: Не получается поместить js код на страницу. Как его правильно оформить? Ошибка: gdpr_privacy_policy_checkbox is not defined

Comment: @Nabla: Поправил.

Comment: Все равно( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @Nabla: похоже, что у Вас этот блок динамически подгружается или создаётся. Тогда отслеживайте появление этого блока и вешайте обработчик по факту появления на странице. Вы же кусок кода выложили, а по нему много не "навангуешь".

Comment: @Nabla: Добавьте пример родителя, куда вставляется этот блок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118409/discussion-between-nabla-and-umodel).